# Dynamic ActiveRecord model labelling for Rails multi tenant applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, label, multi-tenant

I'm building a multi-tenant web app in Rails and need to provide tenant specific labelling to some of my model objects.

Here is a fictional example to describe what I mean:

I have a Role model object that should have a different label on each tenant.

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

In the Photography tenant I need the available role names to be listed as:

- Moderator
- Expert
- Apprentice
- Viewer

In the Journalism tenant I need the available role names to be listed as:

- Editor
- Sub-Editor
- Journalist
- Reader

Essentially there are always four levels of permissions within the app but in different tenants each role simply has a different name.  So in the example above, the photography *Moderator* and the journalism *Editor* have the same permissions, just a different label.

I could use a `has_many :through` association but I'd rather avoid having to join three tables just to get a role label.

```
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, :through => :tenant_roles
end

class TenantRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tenant
  belongs_to :role
  validates_presence_of :name 
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tenants, :through => :tenant_roles
end
```

I've also thought about storing the role labels in Redis (which I already have in place for other reasons) and using the `current_tenant.id` and `role.id` as the key. This should be fast, but is it a bad idea?

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base

  @tenant_roles = Redis::Set.new('tenant_roles') 

  def name(current_tenant)
    @tenant_roles["#{current_tenant.id}-#{self.id}"]
  end

end
```

Any other ideas on the best way to do this?  Is using `has_many :though` the best approach?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use i18n translations. Also: this isn't really multi-tenancy in the way most people would mean when using that term.

Comment: Thanks Mike - It had crossed my mind to use i18n translations, but it seems a bit wrong because it's not strictly a translation.  Could you give some advice on how I would go about doing that?

Comment: Ps - I'm using Postgres in case it's relevant.

Comment: how is it determined whether the person viewing is "Photography" or "Journalism"?

Comment: They will be registered as a user in different tenants. Right now I use a subdomain to determine the current tenant.

Comment: are the Roles the only thing that will be different between 'tenants'? are there only two tenants? I can't work out if this calls for a typical multi-tenant architecture or not.

Comment: There are many differences between the two tenants.  There are also potentially hundreds of tenants.  The challenge for me is that the roles are always the same across all tenants and I only want to change the label. I'm not using a schema based tenant architecture, if I was I could do what you suggest and have a dedicated role table in each schema.  You may have already seen it but this blog has a good run down on the pros and cons of schema vs. row based multi tenancy [link](http://myrailscraft.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/multi-tenanting-ruby-on-rails_4470.html)

Comment: My answer below describes the `tenant_id` scope technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the best bet is to use i18n since it is just a labelling issue. The added bonus being that they are ready for you to do actual translations when the time comes.

You can set up the translation file like this

```
  en:
    tenant_roles:
      tenant1:
        role1: "Moderator"
        role2: "Expert"
      tenant2:
        role1: "Editor"
        role2: "Sub-Editor"
```

Then access the label like this in a helper

```
def tenant_role_label tenant_name role_name
    t("tenant_roles.#{tenant_name}.#{role_name}")
end
```

You will of course need to make sure that the tenant_name and role_name don't change. Maybe use a slug to do that so its not dependent on the name or id.

The other option I would have suggested would be to use schemas but from my experience its harder to manage than using i18n. If you do need to update the Role labels through the app then you would need to use the schemas or some other database option

Comment: Thanks stallard that was exactly what I was looking for.  Once this moves on a bit then I may look at using Redis to store the role labels as described her by Ryan Bates http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends

Answer (score 1):

A good way to solve labelling issues is to use `I18n`. You could define language specific to each tenant, and then just translate the role names. In your example, consider the following:

```
en-PHOTOGRAPHY:
  role1: 'Moderator'
  role2: 'Expert'
  role3: 'Apprentice'
  role4: 'Viewer'

en-JOURNALISM:
  role1: 'Editor'
  role2: 'Sub-Editor'
  role3: 'Journalist'
  role4: 'Reader'

# Optional
en:
  role1: 'Super-Admin'
  role2: 'Admin'
  role3: 'User'
  role4: 'Visitor'
```

I have written a micro [**library**](https://github.com/ElMassimo/i18n_multitenant) that makes it easy to use tenant-specific translations like those above.

https://github.com/ElMassimo/i18n_multitenant

The library was designed to use static `.yml` files, but it should also work for most of the *SQL* or *Redis* backends that are available for `I18n`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question focuses on this Role label example, so I can't tell whether you want your app to behave like most multi-tenant apps do, that is, everything is scoped to the tenant, or if that's the only instance where you need this functionality. I'll just give an overview of typical multi-tenant solutions, of which there are two common ones:

1.) Table scoped

This way, every model has an additional `belongs_to :tenant` association, which adds a `tenant_id` column to each table. You then have to ensure that you scope all your queries (`Foo.where(tenant_id: current_tenant)...` for example, or `current_tenant.foos..`), or you can use one of the solutions out there to do this automatically such as [wireframe/multitenant](https://github.com/wireframe/multitenant), or my (very much WIP) [mikecmpbll/cohabit](https://github.com/mikecmpbll/cohabit). This way your roles table would look like:

```
id | name          | tenant_id
------------------------------
1  | Moderate      |        1
1  | Expert        |        1
1  | Apprentice    |        1
1  | Viewer        |        1
1  | Editor        |        2
1  | Subeditor     |        2
1  | Journalist    |        2
1  | Reader        |        2
```

2.) Schemas

In a database that supports schemas, such as PostgreSQL, you can schema switch instead of scoping your models. This is widely considered the better solution if you're using pg, and is covered extensively in [Multitenancy with Rails](https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails) by Ryan Bigg.

Answer (score 0):

If you have master names for each role I'd go with a serialized Hash

```
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :roles, Hash
end

journalism = Tenant.create :roles => { 
    role1: 'Moderator', role2: 'Expert', role3: 'Apprentice', role4: 'Viewer'
}

photography = Tenant.create :roles => { 
    role1: 'Editor', role2: 'Sub-Editor', role3: 'Journalist', role4: 'Reader'
}
```

or you might even be able to get away with just using the indexes for the roles:

```
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :roles, Array
end

journalism = Tenant.create :roles => ['Moderator', 'Expert', 'Apprentice', 'Viewer']
photography = Tenant.create :roles => ['Editor', 'Sub-Editor', 'Journalist', 'Reader']
```

you could then use a bitmask for storing roles for individual users e.g.

```
journalist.roles = "0001" # viewer
journalist.roles = "0101" # expert and viewer
```

NB: I'm sure there's a better way to store/work with bitmasks than a string, but I'll leave that up to you :)